Numpy: What should I be considering when deciding where to put batch dimensions in my class functions to leverage vectorization?
I am writing some code using numpy that involves vectors, matrices, and functions from vectors to matrices. In particular, I am interested in running these functions over many vectors and many matrices in a way that makes use of numpy's vectorization features for massive speedup over for loops.
What I'm noticing is that the convenient place to put these 'batch' dimensions is not consistent between the built-in numpy and matplotlib functions I'm using, and being relatively new to thinking about these kinds of things, I'm not sure how to interpret why this is the case and how it should impact the way I'm writing my code.
For example, if I want to map a 2D vector to a matrix, such as
def f(x):
    return np.array([[np.sin(x[0]), np.cos(x[1])               ],
                     [np.cos(x[1]), np.cos(x[0]) + np.sin(x[1])]])

Then this function has it most convenient to put the batch dimensions last. If the input has shape (2, ...) then the output is shape (2, 2, ....), so that the position of the batch dimensions are consistent the syntax is very readable and intuitive with how I want things to behave. Since x is to be interpreted as a collection of points in euclidean space, being able to plot the points in something like matplotlib with just plt.scatter(*x) is also extremely very convenient.
On the other hand, if I wanted to then diagonalize this batch of matrices, or multiply them with np.matmul, etc. I'd need to swap axes over to the final ones since these functions all expect the batch dimensions to be in the front.
I have absolutely no problem with tracking this. The crux of what I'm really wondering is if the (small) hoops I'm jumping through to work with get f(x) to work this conveniently with numpy functions is a sign that I'm doing something 'wrong' or 'unintuitive to a new user' in the actual interface of my class methods, even though the functions themselves look a lot cleaner to me as the guy who is debugging them.

Normally leading dimemsions are 'outermost' and change slowest. Many numpy functions work with (...,n,m) shapes - matmul, eig's, etc.  Some will rotate things to accodate other axis specs.  Rewriting the first array build to make a (n,2,2) shouldn't be too hard.

if its a speed issue then yeah, I'd refactor things for performance I think. Thank you!
